# Searching for ordered series in a file

Tags: algorithm, file, sorting, search, data-structures

I have 2 file where each line contain an ordered series of id/value pairs of different sizes as follow

```
(id,value):(id,value):...

(1,2):(3,0):(60:3):....
```

Each line/series is considered a coverage point. File one is a list of all the coverage points that i need to find(this file could be big 5000000 lines +).  This file should never change as it is a master list of all the points I need to cover.  The second file is a run report that is generate by my program.

What I have to do now is write a script that first takes the report file and for every point line/coverage point I need to search to master file and see if there is an exact line that matches the coverage point. I need to find the line number so i can save the number of time I hit that coverage point.

First option I go trough each line in the report file and compare it to each line of the master file

Second option I have some way of initially sorting the master file so it is easier to search

Third option I make some sort of "hash function" that would take a line and give it a unique ID.

Fourth option I use some sort of data structure initially loaded with the master file

- Linked list
- Tree structure
- Database

I think there is many ways of doing this but I want to do it as efficiently and without being to complex . if there are others I can't think about let me know.  Any guidance at this point would be great

Here are a few points as example

```
(53,0):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,0):(56,1):(57,0):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,0):(56,1):(57,1):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,0):(56,1):(57,0):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,1):(59,1):(60,0):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,1):(59,1):(60,0):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,0):(56,1):(57,2):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,2):(59,1):(59,0):(60,0):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,2):(59,1):(59,0):(60,0):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,1):(59,1):(60,1):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,0):(56,1):(57,1):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,1):(59,1):(60,2):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,1):(59,1):(60,1):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,2):(59,1):(59,0):(60,1):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,2):(59,1):(59,0):(60,2):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,0):(56,1):(57,2):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,3):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(60,0):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,3):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(60,2):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,3):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(60,0):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,1):(59,1):(60,2):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,3):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(60,1):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,3):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(60,2):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,5):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(60,0):
(53,2):(54,0):(55,6):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(59,0):(60,0):
(53,1):(54,0):(55,5):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(59,0):(59,1):(60,1):
```

Comment: By "matches the coverage point" do you mean that it is an exact match?  Or does the "coverage point" need to be a superset of the line (ie it "covers" it)?

Comment: Yes @btilly it needs to be an exact mach size, order and values of the elements.  ei (1,2),(2,2) is not the same as (1,2)(2,2)(3,4) or not the same as (2,2)(1,2)

Answer (score 0):

Let m= number of lines in the master-file
Let n= number of lines in the report-file

For 5000000 lines + it is most likly infeasable to load it to into memory. So you have to cope with slow file-IO.

### Some Comments:

> First option I go trough each line in the report file and compare it to each line of the master file

This would be extremely slow (**O(m*n)**) and all of it is very slow file-IO

If you can load the whole report-file into RAM you could do so and read the master-file line by line and search for it in the report-file (in ram)
line in
still **O(m*n)**) but you read both files only once

---

> Second option I have some way of initially sorting the master file so it is easier to search

This would only be an advantage if you find a way to search in the file at random line-positions. [Without extra effort this is only possible if all lines have the exact same size]. So searching would speed up from O(m) to O(log M).
So overall performance would still be  (**O((log m)*n)**) and all of it is very slow file-IO

---

> Third option I make some sort of "hash function" that would take a line and give it a unique ID.

Implementing a hash-function working on files is possible but kind of tricky. You could split up the master-file in a lot of files. Each file includes all lines corresponding to the same hash-value (witch is also the file-name).

---

Fourth option I use some sort of data structure initially loaded with the master file

---

### My Answer:

You cannot keep the whole master-file in RAM (most likely).

If your repot-file is much smaller, you can keep it in RAM.

**1. Approach (quite simple):**

Make a HashSet of the report-file in Ram and than iterate over the master-file (once) and check each line if it is in your HashSet.
Takes O(m) time [+ O(n) to create the HashSet]

**2. Approach: split the master-file in smaller files matching their hash-value:**
Load your report-file and store it in a HashSet. Than for each hasgh-value in our report-file-hash-set, we look in the corresponding master-file-hash-value-part to check for a match.
Takes O(n) time  [+ O(n) to create the HashSet + O(m) to create the master-file-hash-files]

Comment: Assuming spinning disks and a reasonable number of records to report on, your approach 1 is massively faster than any kind of fancy data structure on the master file.  The reason is that disk seeks quickly dominate performance.  But that calculus changes if you have flash drives or a distributed data store to put the master in.

Comment: @btilly: depending on the size of `n` on comparison tom `m` this might change. If `n << m` you might read much less from the disc in the 2. approach. But without detailed information I would go for approach 1 and see if any further optimization attempts are needed.

Comment: You are correct but the tradeoff happens surprisingly small.  If you have a sustained disk read of 50 MB/s in a minute you can process about a 17 GB file.  But you average 2 random disk seeks per revolution, so a 7200 rpm disk can access 14400 spots per minute.  And so your rough tradeoff is that if you are reading more than one record per MB out of your master file, it is faster to just scan the whole master file.  (This is a piece of hard earned knowledge that is becoming less relevant over time, but still can matter.)

Comment: @btilly: Interesting. So far I only used something like the 2nd approach was on a PocketPc (but that used an SSD) and it was a big speedup. So you should always profile the performance and decide based on the readings. I was sure even on a spinning magnetic disc it would be beneficial.

Comment: I'd guess that a BTree would have been even faster.

Comment: @btilly: In my case it was ststic data (so no rebalancing needed) I used a quite simple hash-function that lead to nearly even distributed data on the separate small files.

Comment: The win with a BTree is not the rebalancing, it is that if there is any locality of data then you can wind up in practice not having to hit disk at all a considerable fraction of the time.